# Sin function not working with Differential Equation

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy, differential-equations

I am trying to get the differential equation y'=sin(x) however my differential equation will not run any further as I get the error "can't convert expression to float". If I use numpy with np.sin(x), I get another error "loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable sin method". Here is the code:

```
import sympy as sym
from math import *

x = sym.symbols('x')
y = sym.Function('y')
diffeq = sym.Eq(y(x).diff(x), sin(x))
```

If anyone can show me where I am going wrong that would be a great help as it seems quite simple....

Comment: Don't try to use `numpy` with `sympy` - at least not until you are good at both separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `sin()` with an argument that it doesn't support. `math.sin()` must take a numerical value as its only argument.

I think to fix the problem, you just need to pass the function's name instead of calling it:

```
diffeq = sym.Eq(y(x).diff(x), sin)
```

Or else, you need to use `sym.sin` instead of `math.sin`:

```
diffeq = sym.Eq(y(x).diff(x), sym.sin(x))
```